# Simulating a sequence of events concurrently subject to a happened-before partial order

Tags: concurrency, threads

I am building a strategy game where multiple units(5 - 20) is fighting each other in the same time.

I have a logic part that calculate those actions for each turn, and than pass it to the game engine to animate. This is the list of action that I currently supporting:

- perform attack
- perform miss
- perform taking damage
- perform dying
- perform moving

If I animate all the actions at once than it look messy:

> Unit A attacks unit B, while unit B is not even there, it went to
>   attack unit C

If I animate all the actions one by one, than it looks lame

> Unit A attacks unit B, the other 18 units is just stand and waiting
>   for the unknown...

### How can I find what actions I can perform in parallel?

For now my best solution, is to wait for unit to finish attacking before attacking it, it cover many scenarios but it still got halls.

> Unit A attacks unit B, unit C waiting for A to finish attacking in
>   order to attack him. Unit D attacks and kill unit C.

### Edit based on D.W answer:

This solution cover most of the cases but, I found a hall in it.

Think about the next scenario

> A attacks B, B attacks C, C attacks D

Because each of those action has a dependency on the prevues one, your algorithm would suggest to break it in to 3 sequences.

- A attacks B
- B attacks C
- C attacks D

How ever I would like to break it in to, two sequences:

- A attacks B, C attack D
- B attacks C

I want to use your algorithm solution iff B kills C.

Comment: This seems to be a question about concurrency, not parallelism. And it's not at all about game theory. I actually think it's mostly a programming question.

Comment: I think you need to spend a bit more time thinking through exactly what are the requirements.  Can you frame this as a specific technical question?  For instance, are you looking for the actions that occur in each round to form an [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29) in the "attacks" graph?  Something else?  Right now this question is not well-defined enough to answer, so the first step is for you to  see if you can articulate the precise requirements.

Comment: @D.W. Hope [it is](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28409/build-a-scheduler-to-simulate-parallel-game-flow) more clear now.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman, well, no, *this question* isn't any more clear -- this question remains exactly the same as it was when I made my comment.  My comment was on the latest version (*after* your edit), and reflects your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try identifying all dependencies between actions, then build a DAG that represents the dependencies: each vertex is an action, each edge is a dependency between two actions.  From this you can identify how to perform the maximum number of actions in parallel.  Basically, the algorithm is:

1. Find all the sources.  Perform all of those actions at once.
2. Delete all of those sources, and the edges going out of them.
3. Go back to step 1.

A *source* is a vertex with in-degree zero, i.e., with no edges entering into it.  In your context, it will be an action all of whose dependencies have been satisfied.

For instance, if action 1 must occur before action 2, which must occur before action 4, and action 3 must occur before action 4, the resulting order you get using this algorithm is: first actions 1 + 3 are performed (because they are the two sources); then action 2; then action 4.

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm. What are sources? Can you explain your example with the algorithm?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman, I've edited my answer to try to clarify that.  Sorry about any confusion!

Comment: Wow, now I actually got it. Tnx

Comment: Found a hall in this solution, please review my edit to the question